# Does the PS4 or Xbox One need an internet connection to work?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

My friend does not have the internet. They will not have the internet under any circumstances, but they want to buy a new console now that the Xbox 360 is obsolete. We have both heard that both the PS4 and Xbox One REQUIRE connection to work at all by downloading some patch first.  That isn't an option for me (and no they wont bring it here I already asked and they refused with the words "I don't go near the net ever except if forced to at work").

Will either console just work out of the box?  Whichever she gets isn't ever going to be updated unless the discs of games do so. Its never going to be online, she isnt interested in online gaming at all, doesn't have an internet, or even email.  She won't even have a smartphone or MP3 player.

Comment: The Xbox One def. needs a patch before it can be used offline. The PS4 needs one for many functions (eg, playing a dvd or bluray movie), but I believe games can work without it (though features like Remote Play introduced in a post-release patch won't). It is possible to download the patches onto USB though I think. If your friend is such a Luddite, though, an expensive gaming machine may not be for them, especially as many games will assume an Internet connection exists.

Answer (score 3):

The Playstation 4 does not need an internet connection, however [the day 1 patch does enable a wide variety of features](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/25/ps4-system-software-update-1-50-details/). If all you want it for is to play games though, [it should work entirely internet free I'm fairly sure](http://www.officialplaystationmagazine.co.uk/2013/03/20/michael-denny/)

Games should come with the system update version they require to play, if any, a la the PS3 I believe, but I haven't encountered this yet since the PS4 updates it self...on the internet, anyway. You should also note a few games require day one patches either for stability or performance tweaks which could be a deal breaker. A couple games require patches for higher resolution, and BF4 at the least requires quite a few patches (but it's not much of an offline game anyway).

[The Xbox One needs a patch to be used offline and will be basically dead with no connection or patch of any sort](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/xbox-one-can-do-nothing-without-day-one-update). Again, not sure if you can update the system's OS using game disks like you could with PS3, if someone knows whether you can that'd be great to know. Day one patches are at least as much of an issue on Xbox One though, for example I think Forza adds a notable amount of content with a patch including, I believe, the ability to finish career mode.

Comment: PS3 and PS4 can be updated through a flashdrive if they are formated to FAT-32 and placed into the correctly labeled folder on the flashdrive. The updates can be downloaded from SONY and they provide instructions on how to do the update and name the folders.

Comment: With Xbox one, you can't earn achievements while offline (though achievement progress is recorded in the background and they will pop once you go back online). You also can't access any features except for installed games and system settings.

Comment: Consoles that are currently being sold do come with a variety of updates pre-installed. Your assessment of the situation is no longer valid.

Comment: As of 2019 a new PS4 console will work and can be used to play games without connecting to the internet, so long as the game itself doesn't require any updates. For example, Final Fantasy X/X-2 HD Remaster worked on a new out of the box PS4 purchased in December 2018.