# Does a new Xbox One require an internet connection for first time setup?

Tags: xbox-one

For the launch of the Halo Master Chief Collection, I have ordered a new Xbox One.

I won't be home until late evening, and so I'd like to be able to start playing the single player campaign as soon as possible (At this point I don't care about saving progress, I just want to have a look).

Will I be able to unpack my Xbox One, put the disc in and be ready to play without connecting to Xbox Live for updates? Or will I be required to connect to the internet, sign in to my existing xbox live account, download dashboard updates, game updates etc. before I am able to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Sorry, your going to need some internet for the initial start-up of the Xbox One.**

It is mentioned at `support.xbox.com`:

> **Broadband Internet**
>
> **You’ll need a broadband Internet connection to complete the initial Xbox One setup** and to use some of the most exciting features, apps, and games. Learn how to use our easy connection wizard to connect your Xbox One console to your home network.

It is mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156806/does-the-ps4-or-xbox-one-need-an-internet-connection-to-work) exactly why you need to have wi-fi for the start-up of your Xbox One.

[Source](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/getting-started)

Comment: Why downvoted? This is correct.

Comment: I saw some of the information on support.xbox.com, but I couldn't tell if it was explicitly required (ie I though that maybe they were saying it was required to access their 'exciting' features, apps, and games; rather than being required for the basic operation of the console).

Comment: @MistaGiggles It *does* explicitly say it: "**You’ll need a broadband Internet connection to complete the initial Xbox One setup**". Everything after that *also* requires an internet connection to use.